# Can one add a data.frame to itself?

Tags: list, r, dataframe

I want to append or add a data.frame to itself...
Much in the same way the one adds:

```
n <- n + t
```

I have a function that creates a data.frame.
I have been using:

```
g <- function(compareA,compareB) {
    for (i in 1:1000) {
        ttr <- t.test(compareA, compareA, var.equal = TRUE)
        tt_pvalues[i] <- ttr$p.value
    }
    name_tag <- paste(nameA, nameB, sep = "_Vs_")

    tt_titles <- data.frame(name_tag, tt_titles) 
    # character vector which I want to add to a list

    ALL_pvalues <- data.frame(tt_pvalues, ALL_pvalues) 
    # adding a numeric vector of values to a larger data.frame
}
```

Would `cbind` be better here?

Comment: This is very difficult to answer without extra information. Can you run str(tag) for tag, tt_titles and ALL_pvalues? I suspect you don't want data.frame and actually want cbind().

Comment: I added a little more info to my original question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two methods that would "add or append" data to a data.frame by columns and one that would append by rows. Assuming `tag` is the data.frame, and `tt_titles` is a vector of the same length that 'tag' has rows, then either of these would work:

```
 tag <- cbind(tag, tt_titles) 
# tt_titles could also be a data.frame with same number of rows
```

Or:

```
tag[["tt_titles"]] <- tt_titles
```

Now let's assume that we have instead two data.frames with the same column.names:

```
bigger.df <- rbind(tag, tag2)
```

Comment: Does the order of statement #1 matter? For example:  
tag <- cbind(tt_titles, tag) VS.  
tag <- cbind(tag, tt_titles)

Comment: @oaxacamatt. It would affect the order of the columns.